# Evaluate the following limit without using L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the following limit without using L'Hospital

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5x-2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{4x^4+3}}{2-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I have tried substituting $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ with a and tried to $\sqrt{4x^4+3}$ in terms of a but that failed miserably.

Then I wrote 5x as 4x + x and found out that I can get 2x + ... but that did not help either.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: $x^2+1= x^2(1+\frac 1{x^2})$.

Comment: The hospital? Why would you need a hospital to evaluate the limit?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5x-2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{4x^4+3}}{2-\sqrt{x^2+1}}= & 
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x(5-2x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+2x\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}})}{x(\frac{2}x-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}})}= &\\
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5-2x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+2x\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}}{\frac{2}x-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=& 
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5-2x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)}{\frac{2}x-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}
\end{align}$$

Now we rewrite $2x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)$ as
$$2x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)}=
\frac{2x\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}-1-\frac{3}{4x^4}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)}=
\frac{\left(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{3}{2x^3}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)}
$$
Hence using $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$ we get
$$
L= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5-\frac{\left(\frac{2}{x}-\frac{3}{2x^3}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4x^4}}\right)}}{\frac{2}x-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}
= \frac {5}{-1}=-5$$